# C++ is this a stack or heap allocation?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management

Start with the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

typedef std::map<boost::asio::ip::address, int> Ip2Int;
Ip2Int ip2int;

void
func1()
{
    boost::asio::ip::address addr4 = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.2.1");
    boost::asio::ip::address addr6 = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("de::ad");

    ip2int.insert(std::pair<boost::asio::ip::address, int>(addr4, 1));
    ip2int.insert(std::pair<boost::asio::ip::address, int>(addr6, 2));
}

int
main()
{
    func1();

    Ip2Int::iterator iter = ip2int.begin();
    do {
        std::cout << iter->first << " -> " << iter->second << std::endl;
    } while (++iter != ip2int.end());

    return 0;
}
```

I am learning C++ and the above snippet of code has me confused. In func1 the allocation of addr4 and addr6 are stack allocations (right?). When func1 exists they should be gone(-ish, the memory will hold the value until something else uses it). This originally made me think that my walk of the ip2int map could print garbage. I was never able to make this happen though.

Since I still new to C++ I am not ruling out that I missing something. Does a copy happen somewhere that I am unaware of? I thought both the pair and the map insert calls are just making references. Which should mean they could refer to garbage at some point.

Ok, enough rambling. Is the above code somehow valid or am I just getting lucky and nothing else is coming along to use the memory that was storing addr4 and addr6?

thanks in advance for any and all help

Comment: I don't know boost, but a simple way to check if something is stack or heap allocated is to use the debugger and put breakpoints (e.g. on constructors). And you might have a data which is stack-allocated but with internal fields which are heap-allocated...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you can't tell if its heap or stack created by inspecting the constructor the same constructor is called in both cases.

Comment: I mean to put a breakpoint in the constructor, at runtime, under the `gdb` debugger.... Then, if the constructor is reached, the debugger will be able to show its `this` implicit argument, and you'll have a clue if that pointer is on the stack or on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a copy is made when you do ip2int.insert<..>(..).

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer. (I can't mark this answered yet, but I will in ~ 5 mins) How did you know that? I have been using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ as I work through things but didn't find any mention of a copy being made on insert.

Comment: @user442585: Any time something is "passed by value" (i.e., not passed by reference or by pointer), then a copy is made.  (In fact passing by pointer is really just passing a pointer by value -- i.e., the recipient makes its own copy of the pointer.)  So the fact that a copy is made is something fundamental to C++, not something special to the map class.  (That's why it's not mentioned in the STL reference.)

Comment: When you define the map<A,B>, insert(..) takes a pair<A,B> which in turn for its constructor takes an A and a B. (ie. not A& or B&) I'm sure if you think of A as an int, it doesn't seem weird that the value of the int is copied. An object is really no different in that sense. I hope that made it any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This code is valid.  When you insert the address/int pair into the map, you are actually making a copy of the address object.  So the stack-local address object named "addr4" no longer exists, but a copy of it (owned by the map) does.  It's that copy that you are accessing once the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting into a `std::map` makes a copy of the object. The original objects, `addr4` and `addr6` have automatic storage duration and are destroyed at the end of `func1`, but their copies live happily in `ip2int` (which has static storage duration) and are thus guaranteed to be valid during program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Stl requires that object that use its container of which map is one are copy constructable.   So what is going on hear is `ip2int` is an automatic at global scope and exists for the life of the program.  In Func1 you are creating two automatics and copying them into the map.  Underlying the Map uses heap allocation to contain the values.  When func1 exists the memory from the automatics is cleaned up and there destructors are called, but map still exists and the copies that were created still exist.